# Searchable Spinner not working in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, searchable

I had a simple spinner which i working perfect. Now I wanted to change it that a user can able to search the items in it. By following the below code I have done changes.

**Sample code**

```
//Gradle

 compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'

//activity_main.xml

 <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/searchable_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
// In main activity 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SearchableSpinner searchableSpinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.searchable_spinner);
    String[] names = new String[]{"India","CHINA","UK","US","MALYSIA"};
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,names);
    searchableSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    searchableSpinner.setTitle("Select Item");
    searchableSpinner.setPositiveButton("OK");

}
```

**Output**

On click of the `dropdown`

[image]

**What i have done?**

```
//added the library in gradle 
compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'

//new_form_layout (i have created this)
<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:id="@+id/smart_msn_spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:gravity="right" />

**In My Fragment**
@BindView(R.id.smart_msn_spinner)
SearchableSpinner smartMsnSpinner;
```

Now I have created a `bindListners()` function in which I am binding all the values and I am calling it in my `onCreateView` function

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_form_layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        bindListners(); // here i am calling it
        imsiNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setupUI(mScrollView);
    }
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey("install_id")) {
        isNewInstall = false;
        editInstallId = arguments.getString("install_id");
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_fragment_edit_form));
        setEditData();
        imsiNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resetFormButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_fragment_new_form));
    }

    /*mCoordinatesReceiver = new CoordinatesReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Common.GetCoordinatesAction());
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mCoordinatesReceiver, intentFilter);*/
    return view;
}
bindListeners(){
.......

    //Searchable smartMsnSpinner spinner and adapter
    meterSrArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    meterSrNumAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_spinner_layout, meterSrArrayList);
    smartMsnSpinner.setAdapter(meterSrNumAdapter);
    smartMsnSpinner.setTitle("Select Item");
    smartMsnSpinner.setPositiveButton("Ok");
    smartMsnSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedMeterNo = meterSrArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    });
 }
```

On running my app i am just getting simple drop down list as before.

[image]

I don't know what is the problem and what I am missing as i have done everything that is in the sample.

I have run the sample code in my device and it's working fine. I don't know why it's not working on my app

**Update**

After watching the `logcat`the error i am seeing is

```
Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not a  `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar autocomplete is not recomended

Comment: Why so? It works great unless you have some specific requirements.

Comment: It is because of item click listener

Answer (score 0):

I'm using same library but I didn't have this problem.
Anyway I had others problem both on visualization, Parcelization and Re-Initializing the same view (the scroll down view) with this library.

Personally I extended the "SearchableSpinner" and made this changes:

```
public class BaseSearchableSpinner extends SearchableSpinner
    implements  SearchView.OnAttachStateChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = BaseSearchableSpinner.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String TAG_DIALOG = TAG.concat(".dialog");
    // Dialogs Tags
    private static final String TAG_DIALOG_SEARCHABLE_LIST = TAG_DIALOG.concat(".searchableList");
    // SearchableSpinner Fields
    private static final String FIELD_SEARCHABLE_LIST_DIALOG = "_searchableListDialog";
    private static final String FIELD_SEARCH_VIEW = "_searchView";
    private static final String FIELD_SEARCHABLE_ITEM = "_searchableItem";
    private static final String FIELD_ARRAY_ADAPTER = "_arrayAdapter";
    private static final String FIELD_ITEMS = "_items";

    private boolean mIsListDialogAdded;
    private boolean mIsListenerAdded;

    public BaseSearchableSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initListDialog();
    }

    public BaseSearchableSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initListDialog();
    }

    public BaseSearchableSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initListDialog();
    }

    /** Override SearchableSpinner Methods **/
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        try{
            SearchableListDialog sld = (SearchableListDialog) FieldUtils.readField(this, FIELD_SEARCHABLE_LIST_DIALOG, true);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) FieldUtils.readField(this, FIELD_ARRAY_ADAPTER, true);
            List items = (List) FieldUtils.readField(this, FIELD_ITEMS, true);
            if (sld != null && adapter != null && items != null && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && checkIfListDialogNotAdded()) {
                if(mIsListenerAdded){
                    mIsListDialogAdded = true;
                }
                items.clear();
                for (int i = 0x0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    items.add(adapter.getItem(i));
                }
                sld.show(scanForActivity(getContext()).getFragmentManager(), TAG_DIALOG_SEARCHABLE_LIST);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iaE){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, iaE);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /** Override SearchView.OnAttachStateChangeListener Methods **/
    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
        mIsListDialogAdded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
        mIsListDialogAdded = false;
    }

    /** Private Methods **/
    private void initListDialog(){
        try{
            SearchableListDialog oldD = (SearchableListDialog) FieldUtils.readField(this, FIELD_SEARCHABLE_LIST_DIALOG, true);
            if(oldD != null) {
                BaseSearchableListDialog newD = new BaseSearchableListDialog(this);
                newD.setArguments(oldD.getArguments());
                newD.setOnSearchableItemClickListener(this);
                FieldUtils.writeField(this, FIELD_SEARCHABLE_LIST_DIALOG, newD, true);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iaE){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, iaE);
        }
    }

    private void initListenerOnCloseSearchView(SearchableListDialog instance) {
        try{
            SearchView sv = (SearchView) FieldUtils.readField(instance, FIELD_SEARCH_VIEW, true);
            if(sv != null){
                sv.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
                mIsListenerAdded = true;
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iaE){
            EMaxLogger.onException(TAG, iaE);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkIfListDialogNotAdded(){
        return !mIsListDialogAdded && scanForActivity(getContext()).getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_DIALOG_SEARCHABLE_LIST) == null;
    }

    private Activity scanForActivity(Context cont) {
        if (cont == null)
            return null;
        else if (cont instanceof Activity)
            return (Activity) cont;
        else if (cont instanceof ContextWrapper)
            return scanForActivity(((ContextWrapper) cont).getBaseContext());
        return null;
    }

    /** Private Classes  **/
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public static class BaseSearchableListDialog extends SearchableListDialog {

        private BaseSearchableSpinner mOuter;

        private BaseSearchableListDialog(BaseSearchableSpinner bss){
            super();
            mOuter = bss;
        }

        /** Override SearchableListDialog Methods **/
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
            mOuter.initListenerOnCloseSearchView(this);
            return dialog;
        }

    }

}
```

Try using this and see if it works.

Also I changed the adapter to have custom texts and don't always display the "toString" of an object :/ I normally use the toString only for debugging purposes, so to show info about an object I make specific methods.

So this is the class for the Adapter:

```
public abstract class BaseSearchableSpinnerAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {

    // Empty Item Label
    protected static final String LABEL_EMPTY_ITEM = "                                                                           ";
    // Label Length
    protected static final int LABEL_LENGTH = 50;
    // Spinner Adapter Positions
    public static final int POS_ITEM_NOT_FOUND = -0x1;
    public static final int POS_EMPTY_ITEM = 0x0;       // Not always true, depends if implemented

    protected List<T> mItems;
    private int mResLayout;

    public BaseSearchableSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mResLayout = resource;
    }

    /** Abstract Methods **/
    public abstract <T extends CharSequence> T getLabelView(int pos);

    /** Override ArrayAdapter Methods **/
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mResLayout, parent, false);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_default, parent, false);
            }
        }
        TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        if(tv != null){
            tv.setText(getLabelView(position));
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(){
        mItems.clear();
        super.clear();
    }

    /** Public Methods **/
    public void addAll(List<T> objs){
        clear();
        ArrayList<CharSequence> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        if(objs != null && objs.size() > 0x0){
            mItems.addAll(objs);
            for(int i = 0x0; i < objs.size(); i++){
                labels.add(getLabelView(i));
            }
        }
        super.addAll(labels);
    }

    public T getMyItem(int pos){
        if(mItems != null && mItems.size() > pos && pos != -0x1){
            return mItems.get(pos);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<T> getMyItems(){
        return mItems;
    }

}
```

Extend this class and use the object you want.
LABEL_EMTPY_ITEM is a long series of spaces because in some app when the text don't take all the line in the list view it will be clickable only on the text and not on all the line.. So when you have no item the clikable part of the line is a little small piece on the left (in my case, I had this problem).

Example to extend this base Adapter class:

```
public class MyObjectSearchableSpinnerAdapter extends BaseSearchableSpinnerAdapter<MyObject> {

    private @StringRes int mIdFstr;

    public MyObjectSearchableSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource){
        this(context, resource, R.string.fstr_two_fields_dash);
    }

    public MyObjectSearchableSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, int idFstr){
        super(context, resource);
        mIdFstr = idFstr;
    }

    /** Override BaseSearchableSpinnerAdapter Methods **/
    @Override
    public <T extends CharSequence> T getLabelView(int pos) {
        MyObject item = mItems.get(pos);
        if(item != null){
            return (T) (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getName2()) ?
                            getContext().getString(mIdFstr, item.getName1(), item.getName2()) :
                            item.getName1());
        }
        return (T) LABEL_EMPTY_ITEM;
    }

    /** Public Methods **/
    public int getItemPosition(int idMyObject){
        return getItemPosition(String.valueOf(idMyObject));
    }

    public int getItemPosition(String idMyObject){
        if(mItems != null && mItems.size() > 0x0){
            for(int i = 0x0; i < mItems.size(); i++){
                MyObject item = mItems.get(i);
                if(item != null && idMyObject.equals(item.getId())){
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return POS_ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
    }

}
```

Example Init BaseSearchableSpinner:

```
private void initBaseSearchableSpinnerMyObjects(){
        MyObjectSearchableSpinnerAdapter adapter = new MyObjectSearchableSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_default);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_default);
        mBaseSearchableSpinnerMyObjects.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Example Add your list of MyObject to the adapter:

```
((MyObjectSearchableSpinnerAdapter)mBaseSearchableSpinnerMyObjects.getAdapter()).addAll(items);
```

Example Get back an object from a BaseSearchableSpinner with an extensions of BaseSearchableAdapter with a list of MyObject :

```
MyObject obj = ((MyObjectSearchableSpinnerAdapter) mBaseSearchableSpinnerMyObjects.getAdapter()).getMyItem(mBaseSearchableSpinnerMyObjects.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Have a nice coding and day!
bb